# Port 443 for https request is refusing connection after installing certbot SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, networking, raspberry-pi, certbot

I am trying to generate and use a SSL certificate for my website, hosted on my raspberrypi (Debian operating system) with nginx (version 1.14.2). I already installed the certificate with certbot (1.31.0) by running `sudo certbot --nginx` which worked out well. My .config file for nginx is in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and looks like that:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
  least_conn;
  server localhost:3500;
  server localhost:3501;
  server localhost:3502;
  server localhost:3503;
}

server {

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.example.com;

        # react app & front-end files
        location / {        
                root /home/pi/apps/network/build;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {        
                proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_cache off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Connection '';
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                chunked_transfer_encoding off;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Before I used the SSL certificate with http everything worked well but now I am getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error which indicates that my raspberrypi is somehow not reachable. Since with generating the certificate everything is fine, I guess that the problem has nothing to do with this (only other options is that the config file has some error but this was automatically changed by certbot) but rather with some settings blocking the port 443 since port 80 for http worked fine. However, when I am running `sudo netstat -plnt | grep ":80\|:443"`  I see both ports listening:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8743/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8743/nginx: master
```

Additionally, I have no firewall in use at the moment so nothing there blocks the port. I am glad if someone has an idea what could be the problem here or am I missing something completely different?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the server is listening on port 443 (as netstat shows) the cause of the refused connections  is outside of the server and thus outside of what you provide as information in your question. It might be a firewall on your local system or somewhere in between your server and your client - no idea about your setup there. To narrow this down try to eliminate as much things in between server and client, i.e. first try a client on the server system itself, then on the LAN, etc. Also make sure that plain http still works, i.e. that the DNS resolves to the correct IP address.

Comment: How do you expose your webserver? Is that NAT, proxy or something like that? I would start checking it first if access to 443/80 ports are fine. As I can see you have configured  redirection from http to https - is address in your browser changing to https when you are accessing by http? I am asking because it is not clear for me if your http still works fine after installing certificate (changing nginx config).

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys! I have solved the problem and it was just a problem with my router configuration blocking port forwarding via this port.